# how to do collaborative work on wordpress with xampp in localhost

Tags: wordpress, xampp

I develop with wordpress in localhost with xampp, I would like to invite collaborators to work on the same wordpress project then I create a network and configure xampp so that it is accessible on the other post by entering my ip address but at each once they have access to the wordpress project they only have access to the first page impossible for them having access to the administration login page please help to solve this problem.